# When you're using "here" in a sentence to specify a person, where do the commas go, if any?

Tags: grammaticality, commas, colloquialisms

When you use "here" to refer to a specific person, where do the commas go? Are commas around "here" correct? Because it doesn't look quite right to me...

For example,

> Catherine, here, is our data specialist.
> vs
> Catherine here is our data specialist.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @Barmar, but point out that the use of "here" in this way is a colloquialism. In fact, it might even be purely cultural. When I lived in Texas, I heard it used this way frequently. Now that I'm in Montana, I don't hear it used this way at all. From that perspective, the word is more like "um" or the phrase "I mean" where it's a space filler and not really a contextual word. In Texas, there were no pauses. Consequently, I think the use of commas would fit the culture represented by the speaker, not any rule or form of grammar.

Comment: This would only ever happen in speech, so are you asking how to transcribe it, punctuationally?

Comment: Well, I (UK) wouldn't use a comma at all, and I regard it as a perfectly normal way to introduce a third person who is present to someone who probably doesn't know them.

Answer (score 1):

Commas in this context are used to provide *optional* additional information about the subject, clarifying or further introducing the subject.  Without commas, that additional information is considered *necessary,* and not optional.

For example, compare the following two sentences:

- Her sister, Catherine, lives in Florida.
- Her sister Catherine lives in Florida.

The first sentence implies she has only one sister, whose name is Catherine.  The commas indicate that the additional mention of "Catherine" is simply further introducing this sister.

The second sentence implies she has more than one sister, at least one of whom does not live in Florida.  The commas are not present because the specification of "Catherine" is necessary to clarify which sister is being addressed.

In the case of using "here", the implications might be as follows:

- *Catherine, here, is our data specialist.* (There is only one Catherine present or within the context of consideration.)
- *Catherine here is our data specialist.* (The speaker may be pointing, even, to the specific "Catherine" being addressed, as she is not the only "Catherine" under consideration.)

Having said this, many English speakers today have not learned their grammar lessons well, and might consider the two sentences virtually equal, using them interchangeably, both in speech (where the commas would convert to pauses) and in writing.

Comment: Oooh, I'm burned :)